# EF 6 to EF Core generate different cases for Guid.ToString()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using Azure SQL Server and I am migrating from EF 6 to EF Core 7.

In EF 6, `Guid.ToString()` method generates select query with the GUID in lowercase where as right now, EF Core 7 is generating uppercase. I have used a lot of those conversions in my project so is there an easy way to override the default query generated by `Guid.ToString()` or `Guid?.ToString()` in EF Core 7?

There is already an issue in EF core Github. But the provided solution is not good enough for my case.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24419

Comment: This shouldn't matter provided you're using `uniqueidentifier` for your column type.

Comment: Yes, I am using `uniqueidentifier` in my database table. I am connecting to the same database and using the same table for both `EF 6` and `EF 7`. That uppercase to lowercase change will be a breaking change for consumers of my API if they are directly using them as strings.

Comment: Again, that shouldn't be a problem because (presumably) you aren't using your EF entity classes as DTOs (because doing so will lead exactly to problems like this).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "that shouldn't be a problem". I am not using Entity classes as DTOs. My API used to output GUIDs as lowercase strings. Now it becomes uppercase strings just by migrating from EF 6 to EF 7. And I can't expect every client code to cast them to GUID since JavaScript doesn't even have GUID as a type.

Comment: Does your API return a `Guid` of a `string`? If it's the latter then can't you just add a `ToLower` call to your action to retain the original behaviour? Given that GUIDs are numbers and not strings, no one should be comparing them as strings in a case-sensitive manner in the first place. Unless your API documented explicitly that the text values would be lower case, the fault lies with the consumers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What? How should I put GUID in JSON response then? ISO standard for GUID is to represent it as a lowercase string. So we were following that principle. Then to add `ToLower` to every possible `Guid.ToString()` in the entire project is a nightmare because I also have to check is that is running in CLR or in database since CLR converts GUID to lowercase string already.

Comment: Why do you have to check? If it's already lower case then calling `ToLower` isn't going to make a difference, so you can just do it everywhere. You asked how to make it lower case and that's how. If EF Core returns upper case then obviously you need to do something, rather than hoping for it to happen by magic. Like I said though, if you haven't documented that your app returns lower case and others have just assumed that then the fault is there's. If you want to change your code to account for their mistake, I've told you what to do.

Comment: There is also `Guid?.ToString()` which I can't easily find references in Visual Studio. It will output all `Nullable.toString()` references.

I am not expecting EF to convert magically to lowercase GUID. I am asking if there is 
any way EF 7 do provide or should provide I can override generated query from `Guid.ToString()` so that it is consistent between EF 6 and EF 7.  

Since most client codes are JavaScript, I can't just say "Good Luck".

Comment: @HanMoeHtet Please calm down. No one here is paid by MSFT. I personally am criticizing them for many things in EF Core, since I am watching it from the very beginning and kind of know what, when and why they did/did not something. But here they are probably right. At least from their POV. As well as other commenters. If you can solve the issue in JSon, then better do it there to stay away from this and similar future issues, since now breaking changes are allowed in any major version update. See below for a constructive workaround in case you really need it (even temporary).

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev . I am trying to migrate many years old ASP.NET 4.8 project to ASP.NET 7. I was specifically looking for why GUID string cases have been changed and it turns out EF 7 is doing the change and not from built-in JSON serializer (which is new because we were using NewtonSoft before). Since EF Core is changing behavior I can't check if all strings are GUIDs and apply transformation in JSON serializer side. So your answer helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to mention:

- Like it or not, EF Core (and the whole Net Core stack) has no backward compatibility requirements. For EF Core it's even explicitly stated in the documentation, so they are not forced to provide the same (or even any) translation as EF 6. You can stay on EF 6, or you can switch to EF Core and be ready for breaking changes in many areas.
- In general it is not a good idea to rely on database for string conversions (formatting/parsing) since every database has its own vision, there is no real standard, and also in the most cases it is different from let say C#. So it is always better to work with raw data types and do to/from string conversions client side where needed (like serialization, or UI presentation components etc.). In that regard I don't think we could treat the behavior in question as EF Core bug/issue.

Now on the concrete question

> so is there an easy way to override the default query generated by Guid.ToString() or Guid?.ToString() in EF Core 7?

Luckily EF Core is built around services and DI, thus is much more customizable than EF 6. It's **not** easy, but possible.

For this particular case, there are several ways of overriding default EF Core translation - [IMethodCallTranslatorPlugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.imethodcalltranslatorplugin?view=efcore-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IMethodCallTranslatorPlugin)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) providing one or more custom [IMethodCallTranslator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.imethodcalltranslator?view=efcore-7.0). These are easy to implement, but not so easy to be plugged in into EF Core pipeline (require a lot of boilerplate plumbing code). So I find it easier to replace the default [IMethodCallTranslatorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.imethodcalltranslatorprovider?view=efcore-7.0) service (which is using the aforementioned sub services) using the standard [ReplaceService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.replaceservice?view=efcore-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder.ReplaceService%2560%25602)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method. A little problem is that it is database provider specific, so you have to inherit the corresponding service implementation class (in this case - for SqlServer it is a class named `SqlServerMethodCallTranslatorProvider`). And second is that all these are public (luckily), but marked as "part of EF Core internal API", so you have to suppress the associated warning (and watch EF Core versions for breaking changes).

With that being said, here is the solution for EF Core 7 with SqlServer database:

```cs
#nullable enable

using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static partial class CustomSqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseCustomSqlServerTranslation(
            this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMethodCallTranslatorProvider, CustomSqlServerMethodCallTranslatorProvider>();
            return optionsBuilder;
        }
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal
{
#pragma warning disable EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
    public class CustomSqlServerMethodCallTranslatorProvider : SqlServerMethodCallTranslatorProvider
    {
#nullable disable
        private static readonly MethodInfo ToLowerMethodInfo = typeof(string).GetRuntimeMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
#nullable enable

        public CustomSqlServerMethodCallTranslatorProvider(RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProviderDependencies dependencies)
            : base(dependencies)
        {
        }

        public override SqlExpression? Translate(IModel model, SqlExpression? instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList<SqlExpression> arguments, IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Query> logger)
        {
            var result = base.Translate(model, instance, method, arguments, logger);
            if (instance != null && instance.Type == typeof(Guid) && method.Name == nameof(Guid.ToString) && arguments.Count == 0)
            {
                // result = result.ToLower()
                result = base.Translate(model, result, ToLowerMethodInfo, arguments, logger);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
#pragma warning restore EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
}
```

Put the above in a code file of your choice in the project where the derived db context resides. Then add the following inside `OnConfiguring` override:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseCustomSqlServerTranslation();
```

and you are done - all `Guid.ToString()` and `Guid?.ToString()` projections will be translated as if you wrote appended `.ToLower()` at the end.

And remember, use the above workaround **only** if you are targeting SqlServer (i.e.`optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(...)`).